# Material UI TextField Not Showing Value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a form in react where I'm using a Material UI TextField. I want a value present in the TextField and I can see that it is being set when I use the Inspect option of Google Chrome. In addition to that, I see that the type="hidden". I have changed this to type="text" and to no avail, the value is still not presented. Curious if anyone here has any understanding as to why this would happen. Below is the primary code that is causing the problem:

```
        <TextField
            name="Property"
            select
            fullWidth
            margin="normal"
            className={clsx(selectInputStyle.margin, selectInputStyle.textField, selectInputStyle.root)}
            value={viewProperties[index].name}
            onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
          >
            {propertyKeys.map((key, index) => (
              <MenuItem value={key} key={index}>
                {key}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </TextField>
```

Here is the full code file just for a complete context of what is going on.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Container, Form, Button, Row, Col, Nav, NavItem, NavLink, Input, FormGroup } from 'reactstrap';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { reduxForm, FieldArray, arrayRemoveAll } from 'redux-form/immutable';
    import * as Immutable from 'immutable';
    import _ from 'lodash';
    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
    import BlockUi from 'react-block-ui';
    import MaterialButton from '@material-ui/core/Button';
    import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
    import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
    import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
    import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
    import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
    import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
    import InputMaterial from '@material-ui/core/Input';
    import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
    import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
    import OutlinedInput from '@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput';
    import clsx from 'clsx';
    import { AvText, AvSelect } from '../forms/components';
    import { showNotification, loadPayerProperties, updatePayerProperties } from '../actions';

    class PayerPropertiesEditor extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
      super(props);

    this.uploadRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      errors: [],
      refeshProperties: false,
      blocking: false
    };

    this.showButton = false;
    this.divPadding = { padding: '20px' };
    this.doSubmit = this.doSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleInvalidSubmit = this.handleInvalidSubmit.bind(this);
    this.renderProperties = this.renderProperties.bind(this);
    this.handleSelectChange = this.handleSelectChange.bind(this);

    this.useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
      button: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1)
      },
      leftIcon: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(1)
      },
      rightIcon: {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(1)
      },
      iconSmall: {
        fontSize: 20
      },
      root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
      },
      formControl: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        minWidth: 120
      },
      selectEmpty: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
      },
      container: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
      },
      input: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1)
      }
    }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ view: 'payer' });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { loadPayerProperties } = this.props;
    if (this.state.refeshProperties) {
      this.props.arrayRemoveAll('payerPropertiesEditorForm', 'properties');
      loadPayerProperties();
      this.setState({ refeshProperties: false });
      this.setState({ blocking: false });
      this.showButton = false;
    }
    if (!prevProps.properties && this.props.properties) {
      this.props.change('properties', Immutable.fromJS(this.props.properties));
    }
  }

  doSubmit(values) {
    const { updatePayerProperties } = this.props;
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.setState({
        blocking: true
      });

      updatePayerProperties(values.toJS(), () => {
        this.setState({ refeshProperties: true });
      });

      resolve();
    });
  }

  handleInvalidSubmit() {
    this.props.showNotification({
      level: 'error',
      message: 'Errors were found.'
    });
  }

  handleSelectChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

  renderProperties({ fields }) {
    const inputUseStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
      root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
      },
      formControl: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        minWidth: 120
      },
      selectEmpty: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
      },
      container: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
      },
      margin: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1)
      },
      textField: {
        flexBasis: 200
      },
      input: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1)
      }
    }));
    const selectInputStyle = inputUseStyles().input;
    const useStyles = this.useStyles();
    const { formProperties, unsetPropertiesKeys } = this.props;
    const viewProperties = formProperties[`${this.state.view}`];
    const propertyKeys = unsetPropertiesKeys[`${this.state.view}`];
    return (
      <div maxWidth="sm" className={selectInputStyle.root}>
        {fields.map((property, index) => (
          <Row
            key={index}
            style={{
              display: viewProperties[index].action === 'remove' ? 'none' : ''
            }}
          >
            <Col xs={5}>
              <TextField
                select
                fullWidth
                margin="normal"
                className={clsx(selectInputStyle.margin, selectInputStyle.textField, selectInputStyle.root)}
                value={viewProperties[index].name}
                onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
              >
                {propertyKeys.map((key, index) => (
                  <MenuItem value={key} key={index}>
                    {key}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </TextField>
            </Col>
            <Col xs={5}>
              <AvText
                name={`${property}.value`}
                onChange={() => {
                  if (viewProperties[index].action !== 'add') {
                    this.props.change(`${property}.action`, 'update');
                    this.showButton = true;
                  }
                }}
              />
            </Col>
            <Col xs={1}>
              <MaterialButton
                variant="contained"
                className="{classes.button}"
                onClick={() => {
                  fields.remove(index);
                  if (viewProperties[index].action !== 'add') {
                    fields.insert(
                      index,
                      Immutable.fromJS(Object.assign({}, viewProperties[index], { action: 'remove' }))
                    );
                    this.showButton = true;
                  }
                }}
              >
                Delete
                <DeleteIcon className={useStyles.rightIcon} />
              </MaterialButton>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        ))}

        <Row>
          <Col xs={12}>
            <Button
              color="primary"
              onClick={() => {
                fields.push(
                  Immutable.fromJS({
                    owner: this.props.ownerKeys[this.state.view],
                    action: 'add'
                  })
                );
                this.showButton = true;
              }}
            >
              Add Property
            </Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <br />

        {this.showButton === true && (
          <Row>
            <Col xs={12}>
              <Button color="primary" type="submit">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, properties, payerName, chsId, parentChsId } = this.props;
    const formStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
      root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
      },
      formControl: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        minWidth: 120
      },
      selectEmpty: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
      }
    }));

    const navItems = ['payer', 'clearinghouse', 'parent'].map(key => (
      <Tab
        textColor="primary"
        key={key}
        label={
          key === 'payer'
            ? 'PAYER: ' + payerName
            : key === 'clearinghouse'
              ? 'CLEARING HOUSE: ' + chsId
              : 'PARENT: ' + parentChsId
        }
        onClick={() => this.setState({ view: key })}
      />
    ));

    const overrides = this.state.view === 'payer' ? ['clearinghouse'] : this.state.view === 'parent' ? ['parent'] : [];
    const readonly = properties
      ? overrides
          .filter(key => key !== this.state.view)
          .map(key => properties[key])
          .reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [])
          .map((property, idx) => {
            return (
              <Row key={idx}>
                <Col xs={5}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Input value={property.name} disabled />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={5}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Input value={property.value} disabled />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            );
          })
      : [];
    return (
      <BlockUi tag="div" blocking={this.state.blocking} className="my-2">
        <Container maxWidth="sm">
          <AppBar position="static" color="default">
            <Tabs variant="fullWidth" textColor="primary">
              {navItems}
            </Tabs>
          </AppBar>

          <FormControl
            fullWidth
            className="mt-4"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.doSubmit)}
            ref={form => (this.formRef = form)}
          >
            {readonly}
            <FieldArray
              name={`properties.${this.state.view}`}
              component={this.renderProperties}
              rerenderOnEveryChange
            />
          </FormControl>
        </Container>
      </BlockUi>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const {
    payerPropertiesStore: {
      payer: { payerId, payerName, chsId, parentChsId },
      properties,
      propertyKeys
    },
    form: {
      payerPropertiesEditorForm: {
        values: { properties: formProperties }
      }
    }
  } = state.toJS();
  const unsetPropertiesKeys = {};
  for (const view of ['payer', 'clearinghouse', 'parent']) {
    unsetPropertiesKeys[view] = propertyKeys.filter(key => !_.find(formProperties[view], { name: key }));
  }
  const ownerKeys = { payer: payerId, clearinghouse: chsId, parent: parentChsId };
  return { formProperties, properties, ownerKeys, unsetPropertiesKeys, payerId, payerName, chsId, parentChsId };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      showNotification,
      loadPayerProperties,
      updatePayerProperties,
      arrayRemoveAll
    },
    dispatch
  );

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'payerPropertiesEditorForm',
  enableReinitialize: true,
  initialValues: Immutable.fromJS({ properties: {} })
})(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(PayerPropertiesEditor)
);
```

Comment: Please read the ["How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to learn how to create one. Then share that code, to see if someone can help you. This current question is too verbose as is.

Answer (score 0):

In the `TextField` you are setting value from `viewProperties` like,

```
value={viewProperties[index].name}
```

You are getting data in `viewProperties` from `formProperties` based on `this.state.view`

```
const viewProperties = formProperties[`${this.state.view}`];
```

As you are setting `view` state in `componentDidMount`, on intial render `view` is not set and don't have value so you are not getting any value from `formProperties`.

You need to have a default state,

```
this.state = {
   errors: [],
   refeshProperties: false,
   blocking: false,
   view: 'payer' // default set
};
```

Comment: I made this change you suggested and it still does not appear to work. Again when I inspect the code on the page I see the following <input type="hidden" value="ALLOWED_FILE_TYPES">. Even before I make the code change you suggested the behavior was the same.

Comment: Remove the unwanted code from your post, it is very confusing. Be specific to the problem.

Comment: Which parts of the code do you find to be confusing or not specific to the problem?

Comment: Can you reproduce the code here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-59wdzu?file=index.js